# How to show the extensionAttribute1 using ADSI LDAP and pipe the result into Out-GridView?

Tags: powershell

I need to show the extensionAttribute1 of my computer object in Out-GridView.

This is my script below and the issue is with the two things:

1. Unable to show the result as .Out-GridView
2. Unable to show the extensionAttribute1 value

Script:

```
    $objForest = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest()
    $DomainList = @($objForest.Domains | Select-Object Name)
    $Domains = $DomainList | ForEach-Object { $_.Name }
    
    $FindADComputerName = '*SVR*'
    
$(foreach ($Domain in ($Domains)) {

    $ADsPath = [ADSI]"LDAP://$Domain"
    $objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($ADsPath)
    $objSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=computer)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(operatingSystem=*Server*)(sAMAccountName=" + $FindADComputerName + "))"
    $objSearcher.SearchScope = "Subtree"
    $objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name")
    $objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("description")
    $objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("operatingsystem")
    $objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("extensionattribute1")

    $colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll()
    foreach ($objResult in $colResults) {
            $objResult.Properties.name
            $objResult.Properties.description
            $objResult.Properties.operatingsystem
            $objResult.Properties.extensionattribute1
    }
}) | ogv

$objSearcher.Dispose()
```

However, the ogv does not show the proper data or meaningful column name:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foreach ($thing in $collectionOfThings)` does not pipe anything through like the `ForEach-Object {..}` cmdlet does, so you need to **capture** whatever you decide to output inside the loop in a variable:

```
# capture the results in a variable
$result = foreach ($Domain in $Domains) { ... }
```

Next, make sure you output objects to be captured, not strings:

```
if ($FoundComputer) { 
    # output the desired attributes as object
    $FoundComputer | Select-Object Name, Description, OperatingSystem, ExtensionAttribute1
}
```

Then when finished collecting, you can pipe the results through to Out-GridView:

```
# show whatever was captured in Out-GridView
$result | Out-GridView
```

or save to disk as CSV file for instance

```
    $result | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\results.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

---

You may need to tell the searcher what properties you want returned.
Do that **before** `$colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll()`:

```
$props = 'name', 'description', 'operatingSystem', 'extensionAttribute1'
foreach ($p in $props) { $objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add($p) }
```

---

You have now updated the question, but are still outputting **single values** in your foreach loop. Since by doing that you create an 1-dimensional array, `Out-GridView` will show the `Index`, its `Value` and the type of the index (`System.Int32`).

Instead output **objects** there like with:

```
foreach ($objResult in $colResults) {
    $objResult.Properties | Select-Object Name, Description, OperatingSystem, ExtensionAttribute1
}
```

or

```
foreach ($objResult in $colResults) {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        Name                = $objResult.Properties.name
        Description         = $objResult.Properties.description
        OperatingSystem     = $objResult.Properties.operatingsystem
        ExtensionAttribute1 = $objResult.Properties.extensionattribute1
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the update. however, the extensionAttribute1 is still not showing ?
am I missing any steps to load this property.

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer Please see my edit.

Comment: I've updated the code and the result, but it is strange the column is not informative at all?

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer You are now back to outputting single values. Instead output **objects** like with `$objResult.Properties | Select-Object Name, Description, OperatingSystem, ExtensionAttribute1`